# Built a login form script but it's not working using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events

I am trying to build a login.js script that listens for the login form submit event. When I try to run my code, it's not logging in or working properly

I' working with JavaScript, which is requested to use. I built the login form in HTML and have worked on the login function within JavaScript. It can;t be inline JavaScript, it has to be a separate script from HTML.

```js
var count = 2;

function validate() {
  var un = document.login.username.value;
  var pw = document.login.password.value;
  var valid = false;
  var usernameArray = ["adrian@tissue.com",
    "dduzen1@live.spcollege.edu",
    "deannaduzen@gmail.com"
  ]
  var passwordArray = ["welcome1", "w3lc0m3", "ch1c@g0"]
  for (var i = 0; i < usernameArray.length; i++) {
    if ((un == usernameArray[i]) && (pw == passwordArray[i])) {
      valid = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (valid) {
    alert("Login is successful");
    window.location = "index.html";
    return false;
  }
  var again = "tries";
  if (count == 1) {
    again = "try"
  }
  if (count >= 1) {
    alert("Wrong username or password")
    count--;
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect username or password, you are now blocked");
    document.login.username.value = "You are now blocked";
    document.login.password.value = "You are now blocked";
    document.login.username.disabled = true;
    document.login.password.disabled = true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- start of login form -->
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form" onsubmit="return validate() ;" method="post">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="password" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="email id" />
      <button>Create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Login</a>
      </p>
    </form>

    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="password" />
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Register</a>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

It needs to allow the three login information I put into the code to log into the site. When logging in, it blinks as if it's doing something, but isn't going anywhere nor does it show that the person is logged in.

Comment: is this code on index.html and your redirecting to index.html after success? there is no state or session knowing if the user has failed or success after redirect as this code is all clientside, its not secure hope you know

Comment: The code is supposed to redirect to index.html after successful login. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not validating correctly with the return sentence, also your `onsubmit` attribute was in the register form.

### Use name attribute on forms

This will help you to identify your forms and inputs easily with JavaScript, otherwise you might have problems identifying which input is which in larger forms.

```html
<form name="login" class="login-form">
  <input name="user" type="text" placeholder="username" />
  <input name="pass" type="text" placeholder="password" />
  <button>login</button>
  <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Register</a>
  </p>
</form>
```

With this applied to your login form, you can reference it by doing `document.login`.

### Take advantage over native HTML events in JavaScript

The way you are retrieving the username and password is a lot complex that it should, you can add an event listener in JavaScript and handle everything there:

```js
const loginForm = document.login;
loginForm.addEventListener("submit", validate);
```

This will call `validate` every time the form is submitted. Also, it sends the event as a parameter, so you can receive it like this in your function:

```js
function validate(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop form redirection
  let user = event.target.user.value,
      pass = event.target.pass.value;
  // REST OF THE CODE ...
}
```

This is easier since we added name attributes to the inputs, so we can identify them by `user` and `pass`.

### Validation

> ***NOTE:*** I do not recommend validating username:password data directly in the browser, since this is a big vulnerability and **must** be validated server-side.

You can simplify this validation by binding the username with its password in an object, instead of creating two arrays:

```js
const accounts = {
  "adrian@tissue.com": "welcome1",
  "dduzen1@live.spcollege.edu": "w3lc0m3",
  "deannaduzen@gmail.com": "ch1c@g0"
};
```

And then, having the inputs value saved in `user` and `pass` variables, you can do:

```js
if (accounts[user] == pass) {
    //SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
    console.log('Correct. Logged in!');
  } else {
    //WRONG LOGIN CREDENTIALS
    attempts--;
    validateAttempts();
}
```

With the purpose of not having a lot of code in sight, you should create another function that its only job is to validate if you should block the user or not.

## The result

> I should mention that this will only work to validate the user form, if you need to save a session and keep an user logged in, you **must** use a server-side language.

I leave you a snippet with all of this changes working, see it for yourself:

```js
const accounts = {
  "adrian@tissue.com": "welcome1",
  "dduzen1@live.spcollege.edu": "w3lc0m3",
  "deannaduzen@gmail.com": "ch1c@g0"
};
const loginForm = document.login;

let attempts = 3;
loginForm.addEventListener("submit", validate);

function validate(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let user = event.target.user.value,
      pass = event.target.pass.value;

  if (accounts[user] == pass) {
    //SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
    console.log('Correct. Logged in!');
  } else {
    console.log('Wrong username or password.');
    attempts--;
    validateAttempts()
  }
}

function validateAttempts() {
  if (attempts <= 0) {
    console.log("You are now blocked");
    loginForm.user.value = "You are now blocked";
    loginForm.pass.value = "You are now blocked";
    loginForm.user.disabled = true;
    loginForm.pass.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="login" class="login-form">
  <input name="user" type="text" placeholder="username" />
  <input name="pass" type="text" placeholder="password" />
  <button>login</button>
  <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Register</a>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: This was quite helpful. When putting the information into my code, it still doesn't show whether they are logged in or not. Or it doesn't show if the login attempt has failed.

The only way I have been able to see they have successful login is when I hover a link, the information down in the left corner shows the correct login. What can I do to correct this? Am I still missing something? I inputted your code information in as you've shown.

Comment: If what you need is to show the user something, you can remplace every `console.log` with `alert`, that would be the quickest way.

Comment: Always glad to help. If you think my answer fits your needs, I'd suggest to mark it as accepted so your post is marked as solved automatically. If you still have any question about this post, surely you can edit your question with a better explanation and I'll help for sure.

Comment: When using Brackets editor, the error comes up stating:

 ESLint (1)
1 
ERROR: Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved const accounts = {
 JSLint (2)
1 
Expected an identifier and instead saw 'const'. const accounts = {

What is causing it to not show the login again? If I look in the URL, it shows that it's logged in, but nothing else is showing to identify that they are logged in.